# Magento 1.7 Change shopping cart success page

Tags: magento-1.7

On the checkout success page (http://domain.com/checkout/cart/success) how do I change the layout to 2columns-left and have the left sidebar? When I edit the layout in my checkout.xml file the left block does not render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the left reference. and changed the 2xolumns-left.phtml. Created a directory called "custom" in my theme and inside that directory a custom.phtml. This content is rendered on the left now.

**onepagecheckout.xml**

```
<onepagecheckout_index_success translate="label">
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="core/template" name="customproduct" template="custom/custom.phtml"/>
    </reference>    
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</onepagecheckout_index_success>
```

**checkout.xml**

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="core/template" name="customproduct" template="custom/custom.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

Hope you will succeed !